# Angular 5 Checking the value of a variable on and *ngIf statement

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 5 and I'm trying to check the value of a variable in the html template of the component.

So it looks something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="item='somevalue'">
```

I'm getting this error:

ht Error: Template parse errors:

```
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 17 in...
```

Can't this be done in angular?

Comment: you got a typo, your code should be : `<div *ngIf="item=='somevalue'">`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[***ngIf**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) work like this `*ngIf="expression"` where the `expression` is replaces with the simple Javascript statement which returns `boolean`. But you use one `=` and it means that you assign the `someValue` to the `item` property and if the value is not [**falsy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will return you `true`.

In your case you need to write `*ngIf="item === 'somevalue'"`.

Answer (score 21):

You are making assignment instead of comparison

```
<div *ngIf="item==='somevalue'">
```

Answer (score 9):

You are doing an assignment using single = operator.

Use double equal to == operator to check equality or better use === to check strict equality.

```
<div *ngIf="item === 'somevalue'">
```

Comment: You should use `===` in Javascript instead.

Comment: That's true, but if the developer did not use types appropriately, the result will not be displayed. === is best practice, but == is helpful for displaying results without considering types.

Comment: If you use `==` in your answers, mention somewhere that it's bad practice. Otherwise, OP will think it's the way to go and will use `==` everywhere in his code, especially if a majority of people show answers with `==`.

Answer (score 5):

change it to `item==='somevalue'`. typo probably

Answer (score 4):

**There should be NO quotes inside the out-layer quotes. That is to say, there should be only ONE layer of quotes.** Mine is like the following:

```
      <ng-container *ngFor="let event of events">
         <ng-container *ngIf="event._id===id">
           ....
         </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
```

In the above-shown example, the "**event._id**" is the "**_id**" of the "event", while the "***id***" on the right of the equation is a property from the ***.ts*** file of the component.

Both "==" and "===" work fine. And it **will NOT work** if you put any quotes inside.

Answer (score 2):

use `*ngIf="event._id==='id' "` to emphasize the type of id as a string. otherwise `*ngIf` is meant for boolean not even expressions with operators like `< , >,&&,||`.
on the fact that numbers won't work as expected.
and also expressions like `marksArray.length ===0` wont work .
because 0 is taken to be of type string.

hope this helps